# How to use a custom helper via the "helper" method in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, helper

I'm trying to create a custom helper like this:

```
# app/controllers/my_controller.rb
class MyController < ApplicationController
  helper :my
  def index
    puts foo
  end
end

# app/helpers/my_helper.rb
module MyHelper
  def foo
    "Hello"
  end
end
```

But, I got the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `foo' for #<MyController:0x20e01d0>
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helpers are accessed from the views, not the controllers. so if you try to put the following inside your index template it should work:

```
#my/index.html.erb
<%= foo %>
```

If you do want to access something from the controller, then you should use the include syntax instead of helper, but do not name it like a helper module in that case.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, I do the opposite: I use controller methods as helpers.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :my_helper

  private 
  def my_helper
    "text"
  end
end
```

Comment: I didn't realise you could do that... though in some ways I wish I didn't know now :P (It has great potential to be over-used)

Comment: ahah :) with great powers come great responsibilities ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about just including the helper as a mixin in the controller...

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  include MyHelper

  def index
    puts foo
  end
end
```